# Why do multiple SNES games share the same title screen music?

Tags: gaming, snes, music

Please watch the first few seconds of gameplay of the following two SNES games:

1. Pocket Monster: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbPw6-Z2pkU
2. Disney's Bonkers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kaIh0Lcdhrc

They use the *exact* same title screen music! I suspect other games use it as well. What is the source of this song, what's it called, and why does it appear in multiple games?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason for this is that Pocket Monster is an [unlicensed SNES game released in September 1998](https://bootleggames.fandom.com/wiki/Pocket_Monster_(Mega_Drive/SNES)), and in being an unlicensed game, it does not need to uphold itself to Nintendo's licensing standards.  It stole both graphics and audio freely from many games, including the title screen music from Disney's Bonkers.

I would imagine that the same stolen music track would be found in many unlicensed games because doing so saves development time, which brings down the cost of production.

Comment: Not just the title music -- per your "bootleggames" wiki link, all of the audio in the SNES version of *Pocket Monster* is from *Bonkers*. For example, you can hear the same soundtrack at [2:06 in the Bonkers playthrough](https://youtu.be/kaIh0Lcdhrc?t=126) and at [7:33 in Pocket Monster](https://youtu.be/EbPw6-Z2pkU?t=453).